# ASPxMemo get key pressed

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

How to get key pressed in cliendside from ASPxMemo in javascript code?
I try with event.keyCode , window.event.keyCode , event.which and other but I can't see result...
Thanks!

Comment: this may help http://devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q206768.aspx